# Comment traiter les questions ou traduire les emojis qui ne sont que des pictogrammes ?

Tags: discussion, support, linguistique, pictogrammes, traduction

Une de ces exceptions, voyons donc "[GOAT](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52599/1893)" dont il ne s'agit pas de chèvre, un chèvre *GOAT*  [emoji d'un chèvre] n'a rien à voir avec la traduction de l'acronyme "Greatest of All Time" dont il y en a qui emploient un emoji d'un chèvre pour l'acronyme en anglais. Sinon, même  pas idiomatique, les emojis deviennent de plus en plus faciles à comprendre malgré le fait que l'émoji GOAT n'ait aucun rapport comme c'est un acronyme.  Ce n'est pas phonétique comme @2m1 ou 12C4.

Pourquoi donc  [Des expressions en français qui signifient "créer portfolio papier pour les dossiers" sur un ordinateur](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52800/1893) emploie comme ça   [emoji d'un dossier] qui cherche à traduire . . . quoi ?

Les emojis, c'est ma question.  Je suis loin de l'informatique mais la question là-haut me semble plutôt en en espagnol et en pictogrammes qu'en français.  Qu'est-ce qu'il faut faire ?  Au fur et à mesure comment traduire les emojis ?

Pardon, ça n'était pas facile de mettre les pictogrammes. Comment décoder les images ?

---

Other than exceptions like acronyms, *GOAT*  "goat emoji" for example which has gained use as an emoji in French on social media but is not phonetic in translation, to what extent are we translating pictograms or emojis? I understand a case by case as emojis become more and more popular, but how would French Language SE  like to be responsible for translating what    "file emoji" means?  Are emojis otherwise all on par with decoding the phonetic "CYA L8er"?

After all, are we decoding pictures?  How?

Comment: Since we've been getting an influx lately of computational symbols that are already in dictionaries, glossaries, gen reference, does anyone care to weigh in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd boil it down to this guideline

> **Be specific**
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.

As long as the emojis are explicit enough or just a bit of icing on the cake, I don't see a reason to ban them.

The folder emoji  is quite vague, so if the whole question depends on understanding what the poster means by a dry , I'd be inclined to tag it as not specific enough, yes.
But to be honest I think the Q you linked to has a lot more problems than emojis.

Comment: Merci d'avoir répondu.  Je ne cherche pas à abîmer les questions qui concernent ou contiennent des emojis a priori (pourtant je les supprime quand ça sert à rien) mais je ne comprends pas très bien les questions qui les emploient déjà.  Est-ce que nous, FSE on veut être responsable d'un dico "emoji - français" ?

Comment: Non, et si l'emoji est le sujet de la question, il existe une traduction officielle : https://www.unicode.org/Public/15.0.0/charts/fr/CodeCharts.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons to post a question involving emojis, as answers about artwork are interpretational. **When a question involves an emoji itself, even that meaning may be subjective unless the question is related to the documented usage of the French language regarding the emoji.** French Language Stack Exchange seeks out the finer points of the French language, which may occasionally have overlap in word play but ultimately does not interpret artwork, which is opinionated.

For the purposes of this site, most emoji related questions tend to be opinion based or open ended.

Answer (score 0):

Posting questions **using emojis when the topic does not involve the specific meaning in French or its usage of an emoji helps** create a universal dictionary of emojis and is suitable for this site.

Comment: As a side note, such a dictionary already exists ("symboles et pictogrammes complémentaires A"): https://www.unicode.org/Public/15.0.0/charts/fr/CodeCharts.pdf